# How to return object in conditional statement scope in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm learning java spring. I have to get a user then save the `Foo` into the database. The user object is Optional, so I must put the new Foo in `ifPresent` then how can I return the result while I can't use `let` like javascript?

````java
  @PostMapping("/foo")
  public ResponseEntity<Foo> createFoo(@Valid @RequestBody Checkout checkout) throws URISyntaxException {
    Optional<User> _user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    _user.ifPresent(
      user-> 
        Foo _foo = checkout.getFoo();
        _foo.setUser(user);
        Foo foo = checkoutService.saveFoo(_foo );
      }
    );

    return ResponseEntity
      .created(new URI("/api/foo/" + foo .getId()))
      .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
      .body(foo );```
````

Comment: Instead of `ifPresent`, you can use `map` together with `orElse` to unwrap the `Foo`. Something like `Foo foo = _user.map(<save and return foo>).orElse(<some default foo value>);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 @PostMapping("/foo")
  public ResponseEntity<Foo> createFoo(@Valid @RequestBody Checkout checkout) throws URISyntaxException {
    Optional<User> _user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    Foo foo = _user.map(user -> {
        Foo _foo = checkout.getFoo();
        _foo.setUser(user);
        return checkoutService.saveFoo(_foo);
    }).orElse(null);

    return ResponseEntity
      .created(new URI("/api/foo/" + foo .getId()))
      .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
      .body(foo );
 }
```

the map allows to return another type of object in this case we return the value returned by *checkoutService.saveFoo(_foo);* and we store it in the foo variable, in case userRepository.findById(userId) returns null, you can use .orElse() as comments @QBrute.

```
    Foo foo = _user.map(user -> {
        Foo _foo = checkout.getFoo();
        _foo.setUser(user);
        return checkoutService.saveFoo(_foo);
    }).orElse(<default value>);
```

Comment: There seems to be code missing after the map()

Comment: oh, I misundertand that .map() return an array :(

Comment: Just adding here that the little brother `orElseThrow` can also be quite helpful, especially with Spring's ResponseStatusException